# CSS - A nested element selecting another nested element without using Javascript

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to hover over the "inner" element and make the "hoverbar" element appear. The problem I am having is the elements are nested with different parents. I know it would be easier using javascript but I want to know how to do it with CSS if it is possible.

This is how I have been trying to do it

```
.inner:hover + .other-content .hoverbar{
visibility:visible;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UaXUS/931/

Comment: can you change `.inner:hover` to `.content:hover`? http://jsfiddle.net/UaXUS/932/ Other than that I don't know how possible it would be. CSS can do adjacent and nested, but doesn traverse up the DOM... it cascades downward

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/UaXUS/933/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply style just for siblings only. You *can't* select parent. So if you want to style `.hoverbar` you can do it in **two ways:**

#### 1st is change selector:

```
.content:hover + .other-content .hoverbar {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

#### 2nd is change HTML:

move `other-content` to be child of `content`:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.content{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.hoverbar{
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.inner:hover + .other-content > .hoverbar{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="inner">Inner
        </div>
        <div class="other-content">
            <div class="hoverbar">hoverbar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```